# How do I lex user input in lua without using the LPeg module?

Tags: lua, lexer

I looked at other answered ones (i.e. installing and using LPeg) but found no working explanation. I am making a very basic programming language in Lua (which I know how to do), but just need a lexer for certain things, like variables. Here are 2 of my functions, and I use the string.match a lot in the command(cmd) function:

```
function screen (action, actionvar) 
if action = "clear" then
os.execute("clear")
elseif action = "cls" then
os.execute("cls")
elseif action = "showText" then
print(actionvar)
end
end


function command (cmd)
if string.match(cmd, "screen") then
    if string.match(cmd, "clear") then
        screen(clear)
    elseif string.match(cmd, "cls") then
        screen(cls)
    end
    -- it must be showText or improper cmd.
    if string.match(cmd, "showText") then

    else
    print("Error: Unrecognized screen command.")
    return null
    end
end
end
```

Comment: The idiom for this is to define functions for each command and put them in a table. Then parse each line, extract the command and the arguments, and pass them to the correct function.

Comment: As an aside, you need == for equality checks, = are for assignment only.  Also, you should return nil (not null), even though when null is not defined it will be nil.